# iPad back to previous view terminates the application while works perfectly on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios6

I tried many ways to show navigation bar but it wont work for me. So I put Back button in secondViewController and it works perfectly for me on iPhone but terminates app on iPad.

```
 - (IBAction)back:(id)sender {

        [self.view endEditing:YES];
        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice]userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {

            LuanchViewController* SVC = [[LuanchViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LuanchViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
            [self presentViewController:SVC animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice]userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
            [self.view endEditing:YES];

            LuanchViewController* SVC = [[LuanchViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LuanchViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
            [self presentViewController:SVC animated:YES completion:nil];
        }

        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        }
```

Error :-

```
2013-10-16 18:44:42.775 iOS-test-harness[7095:c07] -[ViewController back:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa2accb0
2013-10-16 18:44:50.193 iOS-test-harness[7095:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ViewController back:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa2accb0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2c18012 0x1e8ce7e 0x2ca34bd 0x2c07bbc 0x2c0794e 0x1ea0705 0xdd42c0 0xdd4258 0xe95021 0xe9557f 0xe946e8 0xe03cef 0xe03f02 0xde1d4a 0xdd3698 0x2e51df9 0x2e51ad0 0x2b8dbf5 0x2b8d962 0x2bbebb6 0x2bbdf44 0x2bbde1b 0x2e507e3 0x2e50668 0xdd0ffc 0x240d 0x2335)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

Comment: Look like that ViewController class has not back: method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be that you have a Class ViewController (mostly a superclass of LuanchViewController) and it is call a method back which is not in the implementation.

Comment: Actually I have method back in two controllers. I have not understood Why same Variable name are not allowed in multiple controllers ?

Comment: They are if classes are not related with each other. IF you have a property in base class then it gets inherited in derived class so its already there. YOu cannot add a new property with existing name in this case

Comment: I,m using .xib file for controllers.Actually ViewController Also has back method . I'm on ThirdController  and I want to go back to LuanchController which is the root controller of all. If it work fine on iPhone , why not on iPad. It looking for *back* method in ViewController instead of linked *back* method in ThirdController ? and ViewController is sub controller like ThirdController

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an [unwind segue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-to-use-them) action method. If you are using storyboards and you have a different storyboard for iPhone and iPad (which is the default) you probably need to make sure the iPad storyboard has the correct view controller classes set in each scene.

Comment: I,m using .xib file for controllers.Actually ViewController Also has back method . I'm on ThirdController and I want to go back to LuanchController which is the root controller of all. If it work fine on iPhone , why not on iPad. It looking for back method in ViewController instead of linked back method in ThirdController ? and ViewController is sub controller like ThirdController